# In SQL Server, how do I capture all external transactions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

My management has asked me to create a new **SSRS Report**, that will show how many calls to **my SQL Server 2016**.  They want to know:

1. How many **external** transactions were called to each database?
2. What is the daily count of the **external** calls?
3. What was the longest (slowest) **external** transaction?

Note, they do Not want to see how many **internal** SQL transactions are happening.

As a clarification, say you have a website that calls data from SQL Server. he wants to know when the web server makes a call to the SQL Server, then when the SQL Server responded. This is what is being called an **external** transaction. We have maybe a dozen different app servers that I need to capture this data from.

Comment: So what is *your* question here? *Your* manager has has given you *your* instructions, so what's stopping you doing *your* work? What have you done so far? Where have you got stuck, or what isn't working (as expected)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the SQL Server Profiler. You can set it to run against specific usernames, assuming these external logins have distinct usernames it should be able to give you everything you wish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Profiler has been deprecated for years, and it is known to inflict performance issues on the instances. It use is should not be recommended.